# Web service for Laravel

Tags: c#, php, xml, laravel, wcf

Assume that I have a third-party database application with SDK that can be used to retrieve data out of the database in XML.

On the other side, I have developed a website using Laravel framework of PHP. The website is supposed to display data from the database of the application.

In regards to above I have the following questions:

1. As far as I understand, I can either store the requested data in my website database or just show it without storing. What technique do you suggest?
2. How do I achieve xml data transfer from the database server to the website?
   Taking into account that I have experience of development in C#, I assume that I have to develop some web-service that would run on the database server, retrieve the required data and send it to my website. So the web-service has to receive the requests from my Laravel website, retrieve data from database server accordingly and pass the xml response to my website that would finally display it. Am I on the right way? If so, could you please guide me on how to code and bind these parts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, just to clarify - by 'third party database application', do you mean a local database which you deal with via the SDK and returns XML? Or do you mean that this is a web service hosted by a third party that provides you XML?

Comment: If you don't already have a webservice running on the source database service, why not run the entire thing there? You would then only need a Laravel app running there and serving requests... If not then yes, you will have to develop both the webservice and the front end application that talks to it.

This is a very broad question... Many ways to do this...

Comment: @RyanLund Exactly, by 'third-party database application' I mean a local database which has its SDK that returns different types of xml messages.

Comment: @Serge The problem is that laravel web site will be hosted on some public hosting server whereas the local database is maintained on the local machine within organization.

Comment: You could simply remote connect to the database within the organization. You could establish a vpn connection and be pretty secure as you will be going throug the organization's firewall one way or another... What database engine will you be using?

Comment: @Serge MySQL is used on the web site end, and Firebird is used by the local application. I want to make use of the SDK and develop web service to communicate both systems. But I am stuck at implementation - where should I start coding? Can you please show me the right direction to dig in order to develop a web service by means of C# for my Laravel website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to agree with @Serge in the comments - there are many ways to do this because it is a very broad question.

My answer was mostly going to deal with how regularly the third party database was going to be updated but judging from your comments, I'm assuming it will be fairly often? In which case, I would likely connect directly to the third party database from your laravel app using the firebird driver found here: https://github.com/jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird (Please note, I have never used this so I cannot comment on it's quality) instead of writing a C# web service. I don't know much about firebird itself but you will likely want to connect using an SSH tunnel or VPN for security reasons.

Then I would either store data in MySQL if you know it isn't likely to change very often (in this case you would use a laravel command, run on a schedule, to pull data out of firebird every [X] days/hours/minutes depending on the data) or, if the data is likely to change on each potential web request, using some form of caching system (redis, memcache, file cache etc) to speed up the web requests.

Sorry if that isn't particularly helpful - if you can provide more information maybe I can help you out further :)

Good luck!

Comment: I like the idea you propose - especially for the fact that I will not need to develop a separate web service. However there is one problem - the third-party database is sort of encrypted. Thus I do not have information about tables and their column structure as well as relations. The only thing that I have about the third-party solution is its SDK. Consequently, I think that development of a web service will be the only way to communicate with the database. But I am currently stuck as I do not imagine the way xml data will travel between the systems.

Comment: To be more specific, yes, I understand that my web service will be referencing some methods from SDK that will extract data out of database so that I will have some xml message in the output. What is the next step? How should I provide the response(send the xml) to my web site? To be more general, how do I communicate my .Net web service with my PHP/Laravel web site? Where can I read more about such combination of frameworks?

Comment: When you say encrypted, how is it encrypted (bearing in mind that I know little to nothing about firebird in general)? If you REALLY have no other option and the data in the database is likely to change regularly, the easiest way would be to write a simple REST api using the C# SDK and then simply use curl to make requests to that api from your laravel app. You could speed things up by changing the data format on the C# side from XML to something more compact like JSON (which is easier to parse on the laravel side anyway) .....continued in next comment.

Comment: Doing it like this would mean that, on every web request to your laravel site, you would make a call (or several) to the REST api you built in C#. To speed things up, I would employ some form of caching - at least for the most important/most used data. If the data is unlikely to change often then I would write a laravel command which would retrieve data from the REST api, save it in a database/cache and the read from that database/cache on each web request.